# I want to add CAPTCHA on shoppingcart.asp as well one-page-checkout.asp page in Volusion, can anybody help me how to do this? Thanks

Tags: recaptcha, volusion

My client has ecommerce store on Volusion and he is getting so many fake orders and now I want  to add CAPTCHA before user login on shoppincart.asp page or one-page-checkout.asp page (before place order button).

My client website is www.featherstore.com

I already contacted Volusion support and they don't have any specific answer about this problem and just suggesting to take their serivce or get this done by their partner.

Answer (score 1):

You can use google captcha for this :

[Google reCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)

It is easy to use... You can find out the code how to put it. You just have to get one Public Key & Private Key for specific domain.

Comment: I have the script but the problem is that I am not able to find shoppingcart.asp page in Volusion ftp and neither in their admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

It's under the design menu in the admin panel, Hover over design, then click on articles.

Once on articles change display mode to list, and find one-page-checkout.asp and shoppingcart.asp click edit and add your code.

For reference use see:

[Volusion File Editor Support](http://support.volusion.com/design/file-editor)

[One Page Checkout and Advanced Shopping Cart Functionality in Volusion](http://support.volusion.com/article/enhanced-shopping-cart-and-one-page-checkout-feature)